# Merge implemented as flatMap

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

Theoretically it should be possible to implement any RxJS operator (except `just()` and `flatMap()`) through `flatMap()`. For instance `map()` can be implemented as

```
function map(source, selector) {
  return source.flatMap(x => Rx.Observable.just(selector(x)));
}
```

How to implement `merge()` through `flatMap()`? (avoiding `mergeAll()` too, of course)

Comment: What is this theory you're referring to? I don't think this assumption holds true at all, even though map and filter are easily done.

Comment: I have heard before `flatMap` and `just` are the only ones needed to implement other operators, but this is the only quotation I have related to this "theory" https://twitter.com/headinthebox/status/610836009278803969

Comment: Does that mean it's cheating to use Rx.Observable.create?

Comment: Hm, it's interesting approach. I wonder if implementation using those two methods only will be much less effective than current one (inside Rx). Definitely it will be simpler and much more understandable.

Comment: i stand corrected :) didn't know about the array returning variant of flatMap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks possible if you take advantage of the fact that flatMap can also take array return values.

```
Rx.Observable.prototype.merge = function(other) {
  var source = this;
  return Rx.Observable.just([source, other])
           //Flattens the array into observable of observables
           .flatMap(function(arr) { return arr; })
           //Flatten out the observables
           .flatMap(function(x) { return x; });
}
```

*EDIT 1*

Using RxJS 6 and the `pipe` syntax

```
import {of} from 'rxjs'
import {flatMap} from 'rxjs/operators'

function merge (other) {
  return source => of([source, other]).pipe(
           //Flattens the array into observable of observables
           flatMap(arr => arr)
           //Flatten out the observables
           flatMap(x => x)
         );
}
```

```js
const {timestamp, map, flatMap, take} = rxjs.operators;
const {interval, of: just} = rxjs;

const source1 = interval(2000).pipe(
  timestamp(),
  map(x => "Interval 1 at " + x.timestamp + " w/ " + x.value)
)

const source2 = interval(3000).pipe(
  timestamp(),
  map(x => "Interval 2 at " + x.timestamp + " w/ " + x.value)
)

function mergeFromFlatMap (other) {
  return source => just([source, other]).pipe(
    flatMap(arr => arr),
    flatMap(seq => seq)
  )
}

source1.pipe(
  mergeFromFlatMap(source2),
  take(20)
).subscribe(console.log.bind(console));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```